# Monitor LSI MPT disk status

Tags: linux, monitoring, lsi

I have some servers with RAID arrays based on LSI Logic MPT chips (specifically the SAS1068E). Currently the only way I'm aware of to get the disk status is to use the `lsiutil` program and view the status there interactively.

I'd like to be able to monitor this through a cron job or other script but there doesn't seem to be a non-interactive mode to `lsiutil`. What do people use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you already try [mpt-status](http://www.drugphish.ch/~ratz/mpt-status/)?

Comment: Yes I tried that one as well. Unfortunately no matter what I do I cannot get any kind of output from it..

Comment: To load the kernel module that enables mpt-status to work: `mpt-status --autoload`, or `modprobe mptctl`;

Comment: If you have your RAID in a non-default SCSI id, `mpt-status -p` will tell you where it is;
Running `mpt-status -i <number>` with the SCSI id will give you the status.

Sorry, I accidentally saved the comment, and took more than 5 minutes editing...