# Monitor LSI 1068e RAID1 mirror status on Windows server?

Tags: windows, raid, monitoring, snmp, lsi

Assuming that a client has an existing Windows 2008 server with a hardware RAID1 mirror built on an LSI 1068e SAS controller, what is a non-interactive way to monitor the array's status such that an alert could be generated if it entered a degraded state?

Something similar to the Linux mpt-status tool would do the trick, per this related question: [Monitor LSI MPT disk status](https://serverfault.com/questions/107322/monitor-lsi-mpt-disk-status)

Update: I noticed that the [README file for the Windows version of MSM](http://www.lsi.com/DistributionSystem/User/AssetMgr.aspx?file=msm_win.txt) includes some notes on SNMP services; however, it is not at all specific as to what can be monitored via this service or how the information is presented/organized. Has anyone played around with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightweight utility which you're looking for is cfggen.

It can be downloaded from [IBM's site](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-63457).

If you're not on an IBM server, the utility should be available from the server vendor in a similar manner. Or it's entirely possible the IBM version will work.

To monitor the array via SNMP, the LSI SNMP provider plugin is necessary. Again, get it from your server vendor though it's possible that another version (such as [the one here](http://public.support.unisys.com/phx/docs/es7405r-g1-1.0/htm/38265427-000/html/lsiSNMP.html)) will work just fine.

Comment: Isn't cfggen a Linux tool? Per the 2nd section of the question, I think I understand how I would monitor this device on a Linux server, but the machine in question runs Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: The link I provided to cfggen does go to the Windows version of the tool :)

Comment: You are too kind, my friend!

Answer (score -1):

check out solarwinds application monitor, its expensive but it might help out.  also check into spiceworks, its FREE and will do more than just SNMP.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a proprietary solution. I just want to be able to generate an event (e.g. a Nagios alert) in the event of a disk failure.